# Console within form Visual C#

Tags: c#

I want to get a console window within my form. Basically when you click `button1`, it runs a batch script(test.exe). I don't want a separate batch window but instead I want it to show up within my form.

I figure there are probably two ways of doing this, either 1, somehow embedding the console within my form, or 2, set `StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;` when you click `button1` and get the output to funnel into a listbox to simulate a console within my form.

I am just a little stuck because I have found methods for doing both but my own testing with the various other methods people have suggested, nothing has worked. But either way, my user needs to be able to send input back to the console.

Which method would be simpler and how would I go about it?

Comment: [something like this?](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335909/Embedding-a-Console-in-a-C-Application)

Comment: [or something like this?](https://jpsoft.com/)

Comment: @JNevill Yes but I am unable to get it to even work with a completely fresh project. Unless I am not understanding something, half of the setup code the guy gives is just variables that are either not defined anywhere or code that makes no sense as to what it is supposed to relate to.

Comment: @Koder101 no, that is not what im looking for

Comment: He's got the entire source code, binaries, and sample application there (I haven't looked at it though, so you might be right). It seems like a rather straight forward library you can install through nuget.

Comment: @JNevill The thing is, I downloaded the consolecontrol library like he said and then to make sure it worked, copy and pasted his entire code into a fresh project but I was getting around 40+ errors. Unless Im not understanding something about the format, I would just say it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleOutput_test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Process sortProcess;
    private static StringBuilder sortOutput = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sortProcess = new Process();
        sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
        // Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        sortProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        // Redirect the standard output of the sort command.  
        // This stream is read asynchronously using an event handler.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        sortOutput = new StringBuilder("");

        // Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output.
        sortProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
        sortProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortErrorHandler);

        // Redirect standard input as well.  This stream
        // is used synchronously.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        // Start the process.
        sortProcess.Start();

        // Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
        sortProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        while (!sortProcess.HasExited)
        {
            Application.DoEvents(); // This keeps your form responsive by processing events
        }
    }

    private void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (txtConsole.InvokeRequired) { txtConsole.BeginInvoke(new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler), new[] { sendingProcess, outLine }); }
        else
        {
            txtConsole.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
        }
    }
    private void SortErrorHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (txtConsole.InvokeRequired) { txtConsole.BeginInvoke(new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortErrorHandler), new[] { sendingProcess, outLine }); }
        else
        {
            txtConsole.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
        }
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sortProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(txtOutput.Text);
        txtOutput.Text = "";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to do this is to [redirect output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). Basically things will still execute as you want, but you will get the output wherever you want/need.