# Redirect output from running process (Visual C#)

Tags: c#, output, io-redirection

I have a console that is running and I need to get the output. I cannot use `startprocess` to start the console as it is spawned separately. I do not have access to the source code, I am simply trying to redirect the output from the console while it is already running.

Comment: `startprocess` is not C#. You don't have access to which source code? What exactly have you tried?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I typed this quickly as I was about to leave work. I cannot use my code to start the console I am trying to redirect as it is spawned from the program I am using my code to start. I do not have access to the source code of the program that the console is spawned from and my code is the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450605/console-within-form-visual-c-sharp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that attaching to already running separate process using managed framework is not possible.

However, It is possible to achieve this using `Console Api Functions` under `kernel32.dll`.

**Edit: The code is Improved for better usability**

In order to achieve this we need to use `FreeConsole`, `AttachConsole`, `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter`, *`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`* and `AttachConsole` from `WinApi`

Declarations of static external libraries:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private extern static IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
  [Out] StringBuilder lpCharacter, uint nLength, COORD dwReadCoord,
  out uint lpNumberOfCharsRead);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool FreeConsole();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
    IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
    out CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo
);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct COORD
{
    public short X;
    public short Y;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO
{

    public COORD dwSize;
    public COORD dwCursorPosition;
    public short wAttributes;
    public SMALL_RECT srWindow;
    public COORD dwMaximumWindowSize;

}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SMALL_RECT
{

    public short Left;
    public short Top;
    public short Right;
    public short Bottom;

}

const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
const Int64 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;
```

We first need to free current console handle because we can only Attach to a single Console

```
private static string ReadALineOfConsoleOutput(IntPtr stdout, ref short currentPosition)
{

    if (stdout.ToInt32() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        throw new Win32Exception();

    //Get Console Info
    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdout, out CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO outInfo))
        throw new Win32Exception();

    //Gets Console Output Line Size
    short lineSize = outInfo.dwSize.X;

    //Calculates Number of Lines to be read
    uint numberofLinesToRead = (uint)(outInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y - currentPosition);

    if (numberofLinesToRead < 1) return null;

    // read from the first character of the first line (0, 0).
    COORD dwReadCoord;
    dwReadCoord.X = 0;
    dwReadCoord.Y = currentPosition;

    //total characters to be read
    uint nLength = (uint)lineSize * numberofLinesToRead + 2*numberofLinesToRead;

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder((int)nLength);
    StringBuilder lpCharacter = new StringBuilder(lineSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofLinesToRead; i++)
    {
        if (!ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(stdout, lpCharacter, (uint) lineSize, dwReadCoord, out uint lpNumberOfCharsRead))
            throw new Win32Exception();
        result.AppendLine(lpCharacter.ToString(0, (int)lpNumberOfCharsRead-1));
        dwReadCoord.Y++;
    }

    currentPosition = outInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y;
    return result.ToString();
}

public static async Task Main()
{
    var processId = 8560;
    if (!FreeConsole()) return ;
    if (!AttachConsole(processId)) return;

    IntPtr stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    short currentPosition = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        var r1 = ReadALineOfConsoleOutput(stdout, ref currentPosition);
        if (r1 != null)
            //write to file or somewhere => //Debug.WriteLine(r1);
    }
}
```

**Improvements**

- `ref short currentPosition` added to `ReadALineOfConsoleOutput` function for synchronizing currentPosition of the Standard Output
- `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` is used to get `lineSize` of the console

  - `short lineSize = outInfo.dwSize.X` is added for lineSize
- `uint numberofLinesToRead = (uint) (outInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y - currentPosition)` is used to calculate number of lines to be read using difference between actual position of the console and current position of the cursor.
- considering `lpNumberOfCharsRead` to avoid garbage line endings

Comment: Found your and other articles about this and ended putting together a small library for just this. Put in on https://github.com/jrnker/Proxmea.ConsoleHelper if anyone else would like to get a jumpstart in doing this.

Answer (score -1):

you need to read 
 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318804/how-to-set-a-windows-hook-in-visual-c-net  Specifically the bottom portion

> Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework
>   Except for the WH_KEYBOARD_LL low-level hook and the WH_MOUSE_LL low-level hook, you cannot implement global hooks in the Microsoft .NET Framework. ***To install a global hook, a hook must have a native DLL export to inject itself in another process that requires a valid, consistent function to call into. This behavior requires a DLL export. The .NET Framework does not support DLL exports.*** Managed code has no concept of a consistent value for a function pointer because these function pointers are proxies that are built dynamically.
>   Low-level hook procedures are called on the thread that installed the hook

Comment: How exactly are mouse and keyboard hooks related to redirecting `stdout`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller bring something to the table here and not just SA comments. Did you read the bold text at all?  User states" it is spawned separately."  Hence the need for a Hook

Comment: The linked article does not contain any of these words: console, stdout, redirect, output.

Comment: So post an answer on how to inject your application into another process in C# to redirect the output.  User didn't start the process they are trying to redirect the output for.  They gave it a C# tag.  In order to inject your application into another you need a global hook. 'This behavior requires a DLL export. The .NET Framework does not support DLL exports.'  Anyways I am done here....

Comment: After you injected into that process, what's next? I didn't say I know how to do it. It's rather impossible in Linux (you'd need a debugger or a system call tracer) and I wonder which concept it would make that possible on Windows. I'm really excited to learn something new. Increasing the bounty to 200.